# Qt required by KDE but not needed because already installed

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, rpm, yast

I'm on Opensuse 42 leap and I'm struggling with this problem:
I have installed Qt in /opt/mypath and I'm using it in ld.so.conf. The problem is that my KDE packages require qt5 so Yast has installed many Qt5 packages. This gives me a lot of troubles when I try to link some libraries that require Qt. Is there any way to make Yast use the Qt libraries installed on my custom path?  if negative, is there any other option?

By the way, I need to use that specific version of Qt, not the one installed by Yast.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to tell `rpm`, `zypper` or one of those to look in locally installed folders. The data about what is installed is inside rpm database...

You should search for a qt rpm (preferably meant for opensuse leap) and install that instead of the local one.

Comment: thanks for the info. mmmm is not possibile to say at least that you want to install a dependency (e.g. qt) or all dependencies in a custom path

Comment: not as far as I know